# C# Expression Tree Accessing Result from another Expression

Tags: c#, expression, expression-trees

I have below method which gives a `Expression<Func<T, Result<T>>>` type.

```
public Expression<Func<T, Result<T>>> GetExpression<T>()
{
    //Do something to retrun expression
}



public class Result<T>
    {
        public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }

        public string Message { get; set; }

        public Result<T> ChildResult { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I have another method as shown below where I want to access to return result from GetExpression method.

```
public void UseExpression<T>()
        {
            var expression = GetExpression<T>();

            //I want to get the expression for return Result<T> from above method call and get access to it's properties like IsSuccess which can itself be a binary expression

        }
```

I want to get the expression for return Result from above method call and get access to it's properties like IsSuccess which can itself be a binary expression. All this without compiling the expression.

**End goal:** Let's think of it as a method call, method M1 returns Result R1 and method M2 uses this result R1 which(M2) has to create its own result R2 but method M2 has to do an Epxression.Or() on the IsSuccess property of R1 with some other bool expression to create R2 so we need the express. So we need to just get the IsSuccess property from R1 in M2 and then use it.

Please suggest how can I achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to get the result of the execution of an expression, you are gonna have to compile it.

Comment: Please try to explain why you want to do that. What is the end goal?

Comment: yes, at some point, I'll compile the expression but in UseExpression method I'm creating new expression which won't be using compiled expression, so it all has to be expressions and then finally I'll do the compilation.

Comment: @Daniel update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but in UseExpression method I'm creating new expression which won't be using compiled expression, so it all has to be expressions

There are two ways to do this.

The first way is to take the `expression.Body` which gives you the inner expression tree, and *either* re-use the `expression.Parameters` to build your *new* expression (assuming it still takes the same parameter types), or use an `ExpressionVisitor` to *replace* the parameters *throughout* the current `.Body` with whatever it should *now* be. If you have a *concrete example of what you're trying to do*, I could illustrate this with a complete example.

The second way is to use `.Invoke` in your new expression, passing the entire `expression` as the first parameter, and supplying whatever your *new* expression wants to use as the parameters as the `parameters`. However, this is *slightly less reliable* if it is going to be passed to something like EF, and it may decide that it isn't supported. If you're going to call `.Compile` you should be fine, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case I need to get the access to IsSuccess property of Result class under UseExpression method. Invoking just the expression returned by GetExpression method will give a complex type, I want to access it's properties.

Comment: @user7784348 do you have a *specific example* we could work through here? it is very hard to answer these things without a specific example. Could you add some dummy code into "Do something to retrun expression", and give an example of what  `UseExpression` would want to do with it, for example?

Comment: I've created a sample proj and uploaded to this [link](https://1drv.ms/f/s!ApmASDp-Ye0DjYsRA_s5myFwcSb2hw) . Please let me know if you have any query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user7784348 perhaps something like this? https://gist.github.com/mgravell/26a9ee17d720e5fda7c1e005fba4e70c - here I've basically explored the tree to resolve the `IsSuccess` assignment, used `AndAlso` to combine them, then built a new binding with that combined result. But there are other ways to do the same thing

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works perfectly! Appreciate your help!